# PostgreSQL: How to get last 2 years of data from today's date

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL and need to know how to get data from last 2 years starting today, which is current_date.
Is my query correct ?

```
select count(*) from table_name where
creation_date >= date_trunc('year', now()) - interval '2' year and
creation_date < date_trunc('year', now());
```

Comment: Why don't you test it? "interval '2' year" should be " interval '2 year' "

Comment: Even if you get the `interval` syntax right I don't think this is what you want. `select date_trunc('year', now()); 2022-01-01 00:00:00-08` will be from start of year not today.  I think you want `select date_trunc('day', now()); 2022-03-15 00:00:00-07`.

Comment: @FrankHeikens: `interval '2' year` is actually the way an interval is written in ANSI SQL and will work just fine in Postgres: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=93526e538309bfd287ebdafc15a7a572

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think the current_date should work fine, not so sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you want a two year span starting from the current date:

```
select count(*) from table_name where
creation_date >= current_date - interval '2' year and
creation_date < current_date;
```

Using `current_date` eliminates the need to truncate `now()`.

Comment: Thanks, this should work once tested.

Answer (score 4):

What About Extracting only Year from the two parts and make just little comparaison like that;

```
select count(*) from table_name where
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM  CURRENT_DATE) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM  creation_date) BETWEEN 0 and 2
```

Comment: I will have a check on this and get back.